# Monodromy of the family of hypersurfaces on moduli space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry, moduli-space

Let $\bar{\mathfrak X}\to \mathbb P^N$ be the universal family of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^{n+1}$ of degree $d$ and $\mathfrak X \to U$ ($U\subset \mathbb P^N$) be the sub-family of smooth hypersurfaces. The family is a fibration, hence we can talk about the monodromy action
$$\rho: \pi_1(U,0)\to {\rm GL}(H^n(\mathfrak X_0,\mathbb Z))$$
where $0\in U$ and $\mathfrak X_0$ is the reference fiber over $0$. We call the image of $\rho$ the monodromy group $G$. (The setting is same as my former question [Monodromy on Cohomology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845794/monodromy-on-cohomology))

Now my questions are:

> 1. Can we do the similar things to the moduli space? i.e. if we change the base paramater space to the moduli space $\mathcal M$, is there exist a fibration $\mathfrak Y \to \mathcal M$ such that every fiber is isomorphic to the correspond hypersurface?
> 2. If the answer is yes, then we can talk about the monodromy group of the family $\mathfrak Y\to \mathcal M$, say $G'$. A priori $G\subset G'$ because there may be a path in $U$ which is not a loop but becomes a loop after the quotient. Is it true that $G=G'$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For 1 I think it's equivalent to ask that $\mathcal M$ is a "fine moduli space". The existence of such family is a strong condition, for example if you look at the moduli space of intervals $[0,1]$ in $\Bbb R^2$ (up to rotations and translations) then there is no such family.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet So, is there some known fact about the family of hypersurfaces (have fine moduli space)?

Comment: Sorry, I have no ideas. The only reference I know about is Mukai, Introduction to invariant and moduli, where they only explain how to construct the moduli space (and I should say that this is already not crystal clear to me). Good luck !